# how to remove chrome pop up from an automated test

Tags: testing, browser, automation

I have this problem, I have some tests of e2e with puppeteer and they are failing because the chrome unsaved changes pop up appears and I do not want them to be saved, do you know how I could eliminate it?

[image: pop up]

I wanna click on the calcel btn of the pop up, or other way to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer has a way of handling alerts. You can Accept or Dismiss it.

https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.dialog

Example from the page above

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
        console.log(dialog.message());
        await dialog.dismiss();
        await browser.close();
      });
      page.evaluate(() => alert('1'));
    })();
```

Comment: it still not working :(

Comment: is that a site you can share or an internal one?